# vs2012 show xaml design and code in 2 tabs

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012

Is ther any way to show xaml code and xaml design in two different tabs. I want to have on left screen xaml and on the right side design view of that xaml?

I am developing windows 8 app in Visual Studio 2012

Answer (score 1):

To show design view and xaml (xml) view side by side

Locate the splitter options on the xmal page editor (There will be three icons side by side on the right hand side of the splitter bar.  One marked "|", another marked "-" and a third showing two chevrons pointing down.  Click on the one marked "|" and you will have a side-by-side view of the XAML and the designer surface.

To show code and XAML

Open both your XAML and xaml.cs files.
Drag on of them (click and drag on the tab) away from the tab dock. You will see a cross shaped pictogram appear in the middle of the window.
Drop the tab you dragged onto the right hand "arm" of this pictogram.

You should now have both side by side.